# QT make app to check if there is an update on sourceforge.net

Tags: c++, qt, sourceforge

I want my QT app to check if there is an update on sourceforge.net. For this I use the request: https://sourceforge.net/projects/kidbasic/best_release.json
If you use this link into a browser you will get some json reply.
So, this is the code:

**app.pro**

```
QT       += core gui
QT       += network
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets
TARGET = app
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp
HEADERS  += mainwindow.h
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QNetworkReply>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QPushButton>


class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

public slots:
    void replyFinished(QNetworkReply* reply);
    void checkForUpdate(void);
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    QWidget * wdg = new QWidget(this);
    QPushButton *train_button = new QPushButton(wdg);
    train_button->setText(tr("check update"));
    setCentralWidget(wdg);
    QObject::connect(train_button, SIGNAL(released()), this, SLOT(checkForUpdate()));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow(){    }

void MainWindow::checkForUpdate(void){
    QNetworkRequest request;
    QNetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    QSslConfiguration config = QSslConfiguration::defaultConfiguration();
    config.setProtocol(QSsl::SecureProtocols);
    request.setSslConfiguration(config);

    request.setUrl(QUrl("https://sourceforge.net/projects/kidbasic/best_release.json"));
    //other urls to test
    //request.setUrl(QUrl("https://sourceforge.net/projects/openofficeorg.mirror/files/stats/json?start_date=2014-10-29&end_date=2014-11-04"));
    //request.setUrl(QUrl("https://ro.gravatar.com/205e460b479e2e5b48aec07710c08d50.json"));
    //request.setUrl(QUrl("http://headers.jsontest.com/"));

    request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "application/json");
    manager->get(request);
    connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
}


void MainWindow::replyFinished(QNetworkReply* reply){
    qDebug() << reply->error();
    if(reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError) {
        //process json reply
        QString strReply = (QString)reply->readAll();
        qDebug() << strReply;
    } else {
        qDebug() << "ERROR";
    }
    reply->deleteLater();
}
```

(To make it work without warnings I take `libeay32.dll` and `ssleay32.dll` from https://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/ and put those files in the same folder with my application - because of `https`).

If I try with others urls I got the correct reply. If I use any `surceforge.net` request, I got this error: `QNetworkReply::NetworkError(RemoteHostClosedError)`.

I make the same requests with https://www.hurl.it and everything seems to be ok. The same results I got with https://httpstatus.io/ too.

How I can get a valid reply from `surceforge.net` with QT?

Comment: If no-one can answer with that partial code, I would suggest you create a single main.cpp file no-GUI [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which reproduces the error (just use lambdas as signal targets).

Comment: I create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sourceforge.net`seems to be closing the connection when the HTTP request's user agent string is `Mozilla/5.0` (this is the default user agent used by `QNetworkAccessManager` when no [`QNetworkRequest::UserAgentHeader`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkrequest.html#KnownHeaders-enum) has been set).

You might have to set a custom user agent before sending the request:

```
request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::UserAgentHeader, "App/1.0");
```

Comment: Wow! You've saved my life... and my mental health! :)